# Собственная карта на Android

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-api, карты

Пишу приложение для Android - интерактивная карта здания. Все карты в основном делаются через Google Maps API, но там используется стандартная карта Google. А необходимо, чтобы отображалась именно своя созданная карта. Вопрос, можно ли, используя данный API, полностью заменить стандартную карту на свою?

Comment: Привет. У меня точно такой же вопрос. Получилось ли? Подскажи плиз как сделал?